# Azure DevOps Web App deployment for Website and API csproj

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm seeking some advice on this configuration;

i have an Azure App Service with two Web Apps,

- W1 = Identity Server 4
- W2 = website, triggered and continuous webjobs
- W1 URL = identity.domain.com
- W2 URL = website.domain.com

i have DevOps CI pipeline for each W1 and W2 which works well, the W2 CI pipeline also builds and deploys the webjobs

what i'm now looking to do is also host an API CSPROJ in W2

so W2 will get;
website (website.domain.com), triggered webjob, continious webjob and NEW API (website.domain.com/API/some route)

examples i have found so far are either a website being hosted in a web app or an API hosted in a web app, but not both....

any advice on how to approach this?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If your API is going to be a separate project, then deploying to a second app service would be the best option. You can; however, configure virtual path on the web app service; see [here](https://carldesouza.com/configuring-virtual-applications-with-azure-app-services-and-apim/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com%20and%20select%20the%20App%20Service.,set%20to%20wwwroot%3A%20Under%20Overview%2C%20stop%20the%20service%3A) and [here](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/11/deploy-web-app-to-a-sub-folder-on-azure/) for examples. But you can find yourself running into [ANCM errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#50030-in-process-startup-failure) if you're not careful.

I would also consider adding your `ApiControllers` to your web project and configure your routing, as necessary.

Comment: would it be possible to embed the project ? i.e.   <ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\apiproject.csproj">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>

Comment: I don't think `<EmbeddedResource />` can be used in that manner to include project files, at least I personally have seen it used like that. Since your API is a separate project, I would the virtual app route first.

Comment: okay so taking that on board, i think i'll head down the path of deploying a new web app in an existing app service plan. that will allow me to create a URL like API.domain.com